# Difference between Office365 and Office Live?

Tags: office-online

I can create and edit word documents from Office Live. So what does Office365 offer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office 365 is Microsoft's cloud offering for the Enterprise. It offers  small business, large business, education and federal suites of tools - amongst them versions of office.
You can read Mary-Jo Foley's articles:
[Ten more tidbits on Microsoft's new Office 365 cloud play](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/ten-more-tidbits-on-microsofts-new-office-365-cloud-play/7725?tag=mantle_skin;content)
 and
 [Office 365: Sorry, folks. This is not Office in the cloud](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/office-365-sorry-folks-this-is-not-office-in-the-cloud/7743?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zdnet%2Fmicrosoft+%28ZDNet+All+About+Microsoft%29)